# Laravel configuring VirtualHost and Spatie Media Library

Tags: laravel-10, ubuntu-22.04, media-library

I installed in 2 computers a laravel project with spatie media library, but in one of them I use virtual host from this link: [Link](https://medium.com/@laravelguy/how-to-configure-virtual-host-for-laravel-2e55e23219a)

Computer 1 - Do not setup a Virtual Host

Computer 2 - Has setup Virtual Host named "media".  "media.conf"

In computer 1 I need to run like "php artisan serve" and do not have problems, but

in computer 2 I write "media.test" directly into my chrome explorer I have this message error:
[image]
[image]

I want to know why this happend?

Note:  I resolve this in computer 2, deleting the .conf file and disable it, and not using Virtual host.  But, why I can not configuring my 2nd computer with virtual host?

I found this differences...
without virtual host:
[image]

with virtual host:
[image]